# How do i get the required required response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I am expecting the facebook comment from this URL

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http://de.richarddawkins.net/articles/faschist-oder-nicht
```

But getting this error message

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "ABZp42kZtrD"
   }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You need to register the application with facebook and provide the access token in the request body

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution is clearly shown in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, the API call requires an Access Token. You can use an App Access Token for this.

For example:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http:...&access_token=xxx
```

More information:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Do you know how to append access_token with given URL ?

Comment: Now i am getting this response

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "CPIvNZoNrr6"
   }
}

Comment: Is this a valid format 

https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http://localhost:3000/articles/faschist-oder-nicht&access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials